# Test for broken links in .url files

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

We need to test for broken links in SharePoint Document libaries (.url files). Using powershell, we are able to connect to the library, download the link files, parse them and then test the actual link. However, we always get back a 200 result (page found) because we are being redirected to the SharePoint login page, is there a better way to do this (we use DeviceLogin because we have MFA enabled)

```
Connect-PnPOnline  -Url $site_url -DeviceLogin
#Get all the items in this library
$Items = (Get-PnPListItem -List $list_name  -PageSize 2500).FieldValues    
# for each item in the list, determine if it's a .url file and if so, parse the
# file to get the link we want to test. 
foreach($Item in $Items)
{
  if (($Item.FileRef).Contains(".url")){
    $text = Get-PnPFile -Url $Item.FileRef -AsString
    $Regex = [Regex]::new("(?<=URL=)(.*)")   
    $link_url = [System.Uri]::new($Regex.Match($text))
    $web = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    Try
    {
      $page_result = (invoke-webrequest $link_url -DisableKeepAlive -UseBasicParsing -UseDefaultCredentials)
    }
    Catch
    {
        $_
        $page_result = $_
    }

    Write-Host "===========================================================" -ForegroundColor Blue 
    $Item.FileRef
    $page_result
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a broken link checker tool that is designed for this purpose would be my suggestion.  They just need the site URL and you can give them a username and password so they can deal with authentication as well.  There are 100s of them out there and they all do the same core thing.  You just need to pick one that fits your needs and liking.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:   compare the url in the ".url" files with the actual document urls in the library. If the link is good, it will match a document url.  This approach does not require giving permissions to anyone to test the links.  If anyone is interested, I can share my script.  It is then very easy to use excel to compare the links to the source library.

The links have to be parsed from the .url file (my code above does that).  The url of each document in the library can be extracted from $Items.FileRef in the foreach loop above.